# Python: Paramiko Unittest exception after running a 2nd Unittest

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, paramiko, python-unittest

**Setup**

1. Currently used Python version 
   2.Packages used are Paramiko, and Unitest
2. Pytest is not used in this test case yet, but I would be very grateful if someone has an idea here that you can implement with Pytest

Currently, I am rewriting various test cases and creating new test cases.

**In my example here is what should happen:**

- Users should be created with different rights on a router / switch
- Created a user "Testuser 1" of the the privilege 1 (very low rights)
- This executes a prompt command he can not perform for legal reasons

  - If he can execute this command the test should have failed. If he can not do that, the test is positive.
  - As last after the execution this user is to log out of the switch / router
  - Now in the next step, a further user will be created (this is no problem at first
  - The newly created user "Testuser 2" should now log in like "Testuser 1". But it comes to this problem here:

**The Exception:**

This is the exception after running the 2 test. Login of the second user, apparently this user is blocked by my router and switch.

```
Exception: Error reading SSH protocol banner Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2044, in
_check_banner
    buf = self.packetizer.readline(timeout)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 353, in
readline
    buf += self._read_timeout(timeout)
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\packet.py", line 542, in
_read_timeout
    raise EOFError() EOFError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 1893, in
run
    self._check_banner()
File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\paramiko\transport.py", line 2049, in
_check_banner
    'Error reading SSH protocol banner' + str(e) paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Error reading SSH protocol banner

connection negativ
---------------------------------------------------------------------- Ran 4 tests in 6.072s

OK
```

**Here you can see the complete test**
**short info: testcore is a special own special packagethat used Paramiko complete**

```
import paramiko
import SSH
import unittest
from test import support

class SwitchAccount(unittest.TestCase): 



def setUp(self):

    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='admin', password='admin')
    if self.s.login():

       print('connection succesfull')
    else:
        print('connection negativ')


    self.s.query_interactive = True



def test_change_Enforce_Enable(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('enforce-Password-Rules yes')


def test_create_user_rights_1(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('add 1 testuser_P1 testuser_P1')  
        q = self.s.query('logout')

def setUp(self):
    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='testuser_P1', password='testuser_P1')

    if self.s.login():

       print('connection succesfull')
    else:
        print('connection negativ')
        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(6)


def test_try_wrong_promp_command(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('aaa')  
        q = self.s.query('trace ') 
        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(6)      


def test_create_user_rights_2(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('add 2 testuser_P2 testuser_P2')
        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(6)


        q = self.s.query('logout')

def setUp(self):
    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='testuser_P2', password='testuser_P2')

    if self.s.login():

       print('connection succesfull')
    else:
        print('connection negativ')


def test_try_wrong_promp_command(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('aaa')  
        q = self.s.query('trace ')   



 if __name__ == '__main__':
 unittest.main(verbosity=3)
 unittest.main(warnings='ig-nore')
 log_file = 'log_file.txt'
 f = open(log_file, "w")
```

For a better overview here again explained in detail

**Used Librarys**

```
import Paramiko
import SSH
import unittest
from test import support
```

**Unittest**

```
 class SwitchAccount(unittest.TestCase):
```

**Setup SSH**

```
  def setUp(self):

        self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='admin', password='admin')
        if self.s.login():

           print('connection succesfull')
        else:
            print('connection negativ')


        self.s.query_interactive = True
```

**The first Unittest**

```
def test_create_user_rights_1(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('add 1 testuser_P1 testuser_P1')  
        q = self.s.query('logout')

def setUp(self):
    self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='testuser_P1', password='testuser_P1')

    if self.s.login():

       print('connection succesfull')
    else:
        print('connection negativ')
        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(6)


def test_try_wrong_promp_command(self):

    if self.s.login():
        q = self.s.query('account')

        # switch to prompt account

        q = self.s.query('aaa')  
        q = self.s.query('trace ') 
        import time
        print('Wait')
        time.sleep(6)
```

**Short break:**

So far the test works including creating the user on the router / switch.

**2nd Unittest**
Now we come to the second test and here the exception is thrown. This even has the consequence that I can not even log into the router and only a cold reboot helps.

```
def test_create_user_rights_2(self):

        if self.s.login():
            q = self.s.query('account')

            # switch to prompt account

            q = self.s.query('add 2 testuser_P2 testuser_P2')
            import time
            print('Wait')
            time.sleep(6)


            q = self.s.query('logout')

    def setUp(self):
        self.s = testcore.control.ssh.SSH(host='xxx.xx.xx.xxx', username='testuser_P2', password='testuser_P2')

        if self.s.login():

           print('connection succesfull')
        else:
            print('connection negativ')


    def test_try_wrong_promp_command(self):

        if self.s.login():
            q = self.s.query('account')

            # switch to prompt account

            q = self.s.query('aaa')  
            q = self.s.query('trace ')
```

**Finally**

***important to me***

- to clarify how this error comes about?
- which other solutions might even help over pytest here
- It pays to install a test suite via unit test or Pytest here?